# query posts whos featured image is this size

Tags: php, wordpress

So, I have two types of featured images on my site, landscape and portrait orientations. The portraits all have a height > 650 px. There is no tag, category or any other wordpress defined field that differentiates between the two. I'm trying to figure out a way to individually query a random post from each orientation with only php.

Here is what I have so far, which is wrong. I'm attempting to determine the height for each post's thumbnail, set that as a variable and then append that variable to each post. Then, query the post with that in the query args array. Hopefully I'm on the right track.

```
<?php

$pposts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'portfolio'));
foreach ($pposts as $post) {
    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
    list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($url);
        if ($height >= 650) {
        $orientation = 1; // Portrait
        }
        else {
        $orientation = 2; // Landscape
        };

    $post->orientation = $orientation;
    }

$arg1 = array('orientation' => 1, 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1); // Portrait query
$arg2 = array('orientation' => 2, 'post_type' => 'portfolio', 'orderby' => 'rand', 'showposts' => 1); // Landscape query

$query1 = new WP_Query($arg1);
if ( $query1->have_posts()  ) {
    while ( $query1->have_posts() ) {
        $query1->the_post();
        the_post_thumbnail(); 
    }
};

$query2 = new WP_Query($arg2);
if ( $query2->have_posts()  ) {
    while ( $query2->have_posts() ) {
        $query2->the_post();
        the_post_thumbnail(); 
    }
};

$query3 = new WP_Query($arg1);
if ( $query3->have_posts()  ) {
    while ( $query3->have_posts() ) {
        $query3->the_post();
        the_post_thumbnail(); 
    }
};

?>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: My question is: how does one accomplish this? How do you query a post or posts based on their thumbnail height? I just provided my non functioning code for further clarification and to show my efforts thus far.

Comment: "Here is what I have so far, which is wrong." -- I'm sorry, but I smiled a little bit =) Beautiful insight!

Comment: My other thought was to add a custom field denoting the orientation to each post. Creating $end errors in my functions.php unfortunately:
http://pastebin.com/8QNkKBxP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting this because it is the full working answer to my question and what I was trying to achieve. Alright, so I took Shibi's code and had the post id's appended to different arrays. Then, I selected random keys from those arrays to reference while calling up post thumbnails. The end result is just what I wanted: 1) random portrait, 2) random landscape, 3) a different random portrait.

If anyone sees any improvements that could be made please let me know. I didn't include my div wrappers in this code since that would only be applicable in my case. I also limited the original query to 100 posts just to make everything run faster (might do some tests to see what number of posts it slows down at).

```
<?php
// Parameters as separate arguments
function get_posts_by_image_size($width, $height, $size = 'full') {
    global $post;
    $pposts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'portfolio', 'numberposts'=> 100));
    foreach ($pposts as $post) {
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        if($post_thumbnail_id) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $size );
            if($image[1] >= $width && $image[2] >= $height) {
            $portrait[] = get_the_ID();
            }
            elseif($image[1] >= $width && $image[2] <= $height) {
            $landscape[] = get_the_ID();        
        }
    }

}
$portrait_id = array_rand($portrait, 2);
$landscape_id = $landscape[rand(1, count($landscape))];
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $portrait[$portrait_id[0]]);
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $landscape_id);
echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $portrait[$portrait_id[1]]);
}

get_posts_by_image_size(0, 650); // Run the function whrere you want.


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You already doing a loop 1 time on all the post_type='portfolio'.

So you don't need the secound query. just build a function for this something like this.

```
function get_posts_by_image_size($width, $height, $size = 'full') {
    global $post;
    $pposts = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'portfolio'));
    foreach ($pposts as $post) {
        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID );
        if($post_thumbnail_id) {
            $image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, $size );
            if($image[1] >= $width && $image[2] >= $height) {
                the_title(); // here you print the data
            }
        }
    }
}

get_posts_by_image_size(0, 200); // Run the function whrere you want.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Shibi! Posting my resulting code below.